# Can I use WebAPIs with DevC++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

For example, I want to make a code that gets a title from the user and searches Youtube for a video with the exact same title.

Comment: Yes, there are many web interfacing libraries out there, like CURL.

Comment: there are solutions on google to help you out with this.

Comment: Note that the compiler is more important than the IDE for this. You should make sure that the library you use is compatible with your compiler and possibly compiler version.